# LDAPAuth:424 Problem accessing LDAP server in liferay application sw360

Tags: liferay

I was trying to make LDAP configuration work in Liferay. Unfortunately I get this error. It list the name Adam Smith as correctly. Not sure what mistake I am making here. I tried giving email address & username. Appreciate if there any help in resolving this.

```
    2020-06-11 10:25:13.588 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-11][LDAPAuth:424] Problem accessing LDAP server
com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.UserScreenNameException$MustValidate: Screen name smith adam for user 35523 must validate with com.liferay.portal.kernel.security.auth.DefaultScreenNameValidator: The screen name cannot be an email address or a reserved word, such as postfix. It must contain only alphanumeric or the following special characters: -._.
        at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.UserLocalServiceImpl.validateScreenName(UserLocalServiceImpl.java:6863)
        at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.UserLocalServiceImpl.validate(UserLocalServiceImpl.java:6591)
        at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.UserLocalServiceImpl.addUserWithWorkflow(UserLocalServiceImpl.java:971)
        at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.UserLocalServiceImpl.addUser(UserLocalServiceImpl.java:785)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:66)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy517.addUser(Unknown Source)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.UserLocalServiceWrapper.addUser(UserLocalServiceWrapper.java:310)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:66)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy518.addUser(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.AopMethodInvocationImpl.proceed(AopMethodInvocationImpl.java:50)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:69)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.AopMethodInvocationImpl.proceed(AopMethodInvocationImpl.java:57)
        at com.liferay.portal.service.ServiceContextAdvice.invoke(ServiceContextAdvice.java:60)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.AopMethodInvocationImpl.proceed(AopMethodInvocationImpl.java:57)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.AopInvocationHandler.invoke(AopInvocationHandler.java:49)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.addUser(Unknown Source)
        at com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.internal.exportimport.LDAPUserImporterImpl.addUser(LDAPUserImporterImpl.java:594)
        at com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.internal.exportimport.LDAPUserImporterImpl.importUser(LDAPUserImporterImpl.java:1081)
        at com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.internal.exportimport.LDAPUserImporterImpl.importUser(LDAPUserImporterImpl.java:151)
        at com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.internal.authenticator.LDAPAuth.authenticate(LDAPAuth.java:357)
        at com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.internal.authenticator.LDAPAuth.authenticate(LDAPAuth.java:505)
        at com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.internal.authenticator.LDAPAuth.authenticateByEmailAddress(LDAPAuth.java:94)
        at com.liferay.portal.security.auth.AuthPipeline._authenticate(AuthPipeline.java:146)
        at com.liferay.portal.security.auth.AuthPipeline.authenticateByEmailAddress(AuthPipeline.java:39)
        at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.UserLocalServiceImpl.authenticate(UserLocalServiceImpl.java:5603)
        at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.UserLocalServiceImpl.authenticateByEmailAddress(UserLocalServiceImpl.java:1277)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor730.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:66)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy517.authenticateByEmailAddress(Unknown Source)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.UserLocalServiceWrapper.authenticateByEmailAddress(UserLocalServiceWrapper.java:462)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor730.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:66)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy518.authenticateByEmailAddress(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor730.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.AopMethodInvocationImpl.proceed(AopMethodInvocationImpl.java:50)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:69)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.AopMethodInvocationImpl.proceed(AopMethodInvocationImpl.java:57)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.AopInvocationHandler.invoke(AopInvocationHandler.java:49)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.authenticateByEmailAddress(Unknown Source)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.UserLocalServiceUtil.authenticateByEmailAddress(UserLocalServiceUtil.java:437)
        at com.liferay.portal.security.auth.session.AuthenticatedSessionManagerImpl._getAuthenticatedUser(AuthenticatedSessionManagerImpl.java:491)
        at com.liferay.portal.security.auth.session.AuthenticatedSessionManagerImpl.login(AuthenticatedSessionManagerImpl.java:137)
        at com.liferay.login.web.internal.portlet.action.LoginMVCActionCommand.login(LoginMVCActionCommand.java:208)
        at com.liferay.login.web.internal.portlet.action.LoginMVCActionCommand.doProcessAction(LoginMVCActionCommand.java:99)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.BaseMVCActionCommand.processAction(BaseMVCActionCommand.java:61)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.callActionMethod(MVCPortlet.java:378)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.processAction(LiferayPortlet.java:88)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.processAction(MVCPortlet.java:260)
        at com.liferay.portlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:77)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:50)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:115)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.EndpointRegistration.service(EndpointRegistration.java:153)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ResponseStateHandler.processRequest(ResponseStateHandler.java:62)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.context.DispatchTargets.doDispatch(DispatchTargets.java:120)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:48)
        at com.liferay.portlet.internal.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:589)
        at com.liferay.portlet.internal.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:632)
        at com.liferay.portlet.internal.InvokerPortletImpl.processAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:304)
        at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.portlet.MonitoringInvokerPortlet.processAction(MonitoringInvokerPortlet.java:213)
        at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletContainerImpl._processAction(PortletContainerImpl.java:521)
        at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletContainerImpl.lambda$processAction$0(PortletContainerImpl.java:150)
        at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletContainerImpl._preserveGroupIds(PortletContainerImpl.java:425)
        at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletContainerImpl.processAction(PortletContainerImpl.java:143)
        at com.liferay.portlet.SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.processAction(SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.java:93)
        at com.liferay.portlet.RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.processAction(RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.java:76)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerUtil.processAction(PortletContainerUtil.java:118)
        at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:346)
        at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:170)
        at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor._process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:415)
        at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:155)
        at com.liferay.portal.internal.servlet.MainServlet.doPost(MainServlet.java:215)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
        at com.liferay.portal.internal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:622)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:124)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:147)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.uploadservletrequest.UploadServletRequestFilter.processFilter(UploadServletRequestFilter.java:112)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.password.modified.PasswordModifiedFilter.processFilter(PasswordModifiedFilter.java:62)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:147)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.BaseAuthFilter.processFilter(BaseAuthFilter.java:357)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:147)
        at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.servlet.filter.MonitoringFilter.processFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:182)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:104)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
        at com.liferay.friendly.url.internal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:409)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ServletAdapter.service(ServletAdapter.java:99)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:124)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:147)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.uploadservletrequest.UploadServletRequestFilter.processFilter(UploadServletRequestFilter.java:112)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:147)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.i18n.I18nFilter.processFilter(I18nFilter.java:368)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.password.modified.PasswordModifiedFilter.processFilter(PasswordModifiedFilter.java:62)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:147)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.BaseAuthFilter.processFilter(BaseAuthFilter.java:357)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:147)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.etag.ETagFilter.processFilter(ETagFilter.java:87)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:147)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:264)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:147)
        at com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:88)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:147)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:268)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:147)
        at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.servlet.filter.MonitoringFilter.processFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:182)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:196)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:99)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:196)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:99)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:389)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.processFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:65)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:175)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:99)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:175)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:99)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:196)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:99)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:104)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-06-11 10:25:13.812 WARN  [http-nio-8080-exec-4][PortalImpl:1016] Redirect URL https://sw360.company.com:8443/web/guest/home?p_p_id=com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_state_rcv=1 is not allowed
```

Liferay app url: https://sw360.company.com:8443
Regarding the ldap we already configured successfully in jenkins application. We applied the same here . But not sure if app has difficult in parsing the response from the LDAP. We also configured successfuly in another application called fossology. SO I am pretty much sure the LDAP config works successfully.
There is a problem connecting only to the Liferay application.

Comment: Voting to close as off topic (please read [help/on-topic]) as this is a configuration, not a software development question. Suspecting it's the space in the screen name.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but for anyone with the same error add this to your portal-ext.properties file

```
users.screen.name.special.characters=-._( ),
```